# Какой шаблон применить для автомата прохождения квестов с большим числом шагов?

Tags: delphi, разработка-игр, шаблоны-проектирования, бот, конечные-автоматы

Есть скрипт для бота, для прохождения квестов в одной игре ММО игре мною созданный и спроектированный.

Проблема в том, что он мне не нравится, так как я применил анти-паттерн (сам того тогда не осознавая, дело было давненько) **Божественный Объект** (*God Object*).

**Как работает скрипт**

Когда я его писал, я думал о конечном автомате, который переходит из одного состояния после выполнения очередного шага. Если шаг, скажем, 87 выполнится успешно, то автомат перейдёт к следующему шагу 88. Если шаг квеста 87 сфейлится (например, на бота нападёт другой игрок и помешает поговорить с NPC), то шаг повторится и автомат снова перейдет в состояние 87. В каждом состоянии возможна обработка ошибок и команда JumpStep, благодаря которой можно перейти из состояния 87 в 65 или любое другое (для обработки случая смерти в середине квеста).

Проблема: как это всё реализовать в виде кода?

Создавать массив объектов и функций или лепить гигантский case of (aka switch в С++) мне очень не хотелось, потому что это все кушает оперативку + когда придется добавлять новый метод, придётся редактировать этот array/case.
Я решил проблему используя RTTI фишку паскаля, благодаря которой можно **вызвать метод объекта по его имени**. Получился класс с кучей шагов Step1 Step2 ... Step120. Внутри автомата храню номер шага и когда надо перейти к следующему шагу, просто вызываю кодом вида: `call_method ('Step'+intToStr(Step_Num));`

В реальности код выглядит вот так (S - это Step):

```
procedure TSE.S76;
  begin
      StepRes:=Go('Шнаин') and (Q([NPC_Shnain,DLG_Ischeznuvshiy_Sakum__v_protsesse_,1,1]) or WaitQS(Qu20,-1));
  end;
  {----------------------}
  const Qu21=10334;
  procedure TSE.S77;
  begin
      StepRes:=Go('Шнаин') and (Q([NPC_Shnain,DLG_Osmotr_kholma_Vetryanyykh_Melynits,1,1]) or WaitQS(Qu21,1));
  end;
  {----------------------}
  procedure TSE.S78;
  begin
    StepRes:=true;
    if PosOutRange('Gludio',5000) then
      StepRes:=Escape(TravelSoe);
    StepRes:=StepRes and Go('Батис') and (Q([NPC_Batis, DLG_Osmotr_kholma_Vetryanyykh_Melynits__v_protsesse_,1,1]) or WaitQS(Qu21,-1));
    if stepRes then
      prs['DqusetWeapon']:=QEvents.LastItemAdd;
  end;
```

Решение хорошо в том плане, что при добавлении новых шагов не надо редактировать всякие кейсы и массивы. Просто пишешь новый метод Step121 и всё.

Но такое решение мне не нравится по многим причинам:

1. Все методы находятся в оперативной памяти даже когда они не нужны. Да, windows хитро устроена в плане выгрузки\подгрузки исполняемых страниц кода с диска по мере надобности, но всё-таки полагаться на OS в таком вопросе не хотелось бы.
2. Применен антипатерн "божественый объект", в результате весь код в одном объекте, а хотелось бы найти хороший паттерн для такого случая который эллегатно решал все мои проблемы. Не может быть, чтобы его не было, есть же игры типа GTA - там же мощные заскриптованые сцены, где с NPC все что угодно может пойти не так (типа другу главного героя перегородит путь машина и ему придётся её обходить или еще что-нить непредвиденное) и должна быть обработка таких случаев.

Comment: Стоит пройтись профайлером и/или детектором утечек памяти пару раз и проверить, действительно ли у вас есть проблемы с перерасходом памяти. А то как замечено ниже, вы тратите дни на экономию килобайтов, там где это совершенно не критично.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, к вашему случаю идеально подходит State Machine — тот самый конечный автомат, который вы реализуете.

1. Определите по классу на каждый экран.
2. Напишите общий интерфейс `IStateRunner` с методом `Run: boolean`. Пусть все классы из пункта 1 имплементируют этот интерфейс.
3. Теперь определите само дерево состояний примерно такого вида: `type Node = class IStateRunner^ runner; Node^ transitionOnSuccess; Node^ transitionOnFailure; end;`
4. Постройте само дерево (его элементы).

Теперь ваш управляющий код будет прост:

```
Node^ state := initialState;
while (state <> finalState)
begin
    result = state^.runner^.Run();
    if (result) then
        state := state^.transitionOnSuccess;
    else
        state := state^.transitionOnFailure;
end
```

(я давненько не писал на паскале, может быть, ошибся с синтаксисом).

Преимущества:

1. Код каждого уровня отделён от других уровней.
2. Для перехода и общей логики верхнего уровня у вас отдельный, простой код.

Недостатки:

1. Возможно, потеряна гибкость (где-то есть более одного transition'а при успехе? переход зависит от истории?) Для неё придётся писать «виртуальные» состояния или применять ещё какие-нибудь трюки.
2. Код, связывающий классы в дерево, может оказаться малообозрим и нескриптуем.

Comment: Да паттер State не плохой. Однако не  понял зачем возвращать из состояний Boolean когда можно напрямую возвращать следующее состояние. И еще Вы предлагаете на этапе инициализации стоить дерево. Дерево будет большим. Скрипт будет переходить из одного состояния в другое в течении 1-2 недель непрерывной работы. Мне кажется это слегка расточительное распоряжение памятью. Кроме того Шагов всего 170 это значит что придется создавать 170 классов CState1 .. CState170. Как то это не очень эллегантно. Про виртуальные состояния вообще не понял что это за зверь такой?

Comment: @mikserok: Можно возвращать и прямо состояние. Но при этом каждое состояние должно будет _знать_ о каждом другом, а это как-то не очень.

Comment: 170 экземпляров объекта? Это _очень маленькое_ дерево. Вам жалко двух килобайт памяти?

Comment: «Виртуальное состояние» — ну например, состояние, которое держит внутри указатели на несколько других состояний, и в методе Run запускает то или другое по своему внутреннему алгоритму.

Comment: Классы в точности отвечают вашему заданию. Если у вас ест именно 170 «комнат», то вам надо и 170 отдельных классов, реализующих их логику. Другое дело, что вы можете расшарить код между классами, используя вспомогательные классы.

Comment: `Код, связывающий классы в дерево` код связывающий классы в дерево будет нечитаемым и его модификация  в случае внесения изменений может закончится печально. Вы видели какой нибудь реальный проект где использовалась бы подобная техника?

Comment: @mikserok: Да. Но это уже существенно лучше, чем код божественного объекта, который содержит всё дерево (в неявном виде) и ещё много чего.

Comment: Да, видел. Если вы хотите сделать код более визуальным, вынесите описание дерева в скрипт на подходящем DSL, который создаст код связывающей функции.